# <identifier> expected, arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having trouble with some java code. The program consists of about 7 files, but I will try to keep it short.

I'm trying to load an ArrayList from a file into a variable, with ObjectStream. It gave me a warning, because all the compiler could see, was that I said an Object should be casted to ArrayList. of course the compiler won't know what kind of object there is in the file. As the coder I know that the file can only consist of one ArrayList and nothing else. So I searched the web, and found out to supress the warning, nut now it give me the error:

```
Schedule.java:34: error: <identifier> expected
```

To give you a picture of what's happening, here is the code the error happens in. This error shouldn't be affected by any of the other classes

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Schedule
{
    private static ArrayList<Appointment> schedule; 
    private static File file;

    private static ObjectInputStream objIn;
    private static boolean exit;
    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        initializeSchedule();
        System.out.println("Welcome!");
        while(!exit){
            System.out.print("write command: ");
            Menu.next(in.next());
        }
    }

    public static void initializeSchedule()
    {
        try{
            file = new File("Schedule.ca");
            if(!file.exists()){
                schedule = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
            }
            else{
                objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Schedule.ca"));
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                schedule = (ArrayList<Appointment>)objIn.readObject();  
                objIn.close();
            } 
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Exception thrown  :" + e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("Exception thrown  :" + e);
        }   
    }

    public static void exit()
    {
        exit = true;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Appointment> getSchedule()
    {
        return schedule;
    }

}
```

the error is in initializeSchedule, right under the supression, where schedule is set to the ObjectStream input.

Comment: It will work if you annotate the whole method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't annotate an assignment. Move the

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

to the line before the method starts.

Answer (score 2):

The correct locations for `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` are

> TYPE, FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,CONSTRUCTOR,LOCAL_VARIABLE

So the compiler cannot parse [@SuppressWarnings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) at this point, but considers it a statement. If you move it above the method declaration or above the declaration of schedule, it should be fine.

A better way to fix that is to actually correct the issue that the compiler is complaining about like this:

```
final Object input = objIn.readObject();
if (input instanceof ArrayList) {
  schedule = (ArrayList<Appointment>) input;
} else {
  throw new IllegalStateException(); // or whatever suits you
}
```